# Error importing site-package when using Boost Python/Numpy to call C++ code from Python

Tags: python, c++, numpy, boost, boost-python

at the moment I try to implement a simple C++ wrapper for Python. I use the Boost Python/Numpy extension for this purpose. I have the following bash script for compiling the C++ code and running my Python script:

```
#!/bin/bash
PYTHON=<PATH-TO-CONDA>/miniconda3/bin/python3.8
BOOSTINCLUDE=<PATH-TO-BOOST>/boost_1_75_0
PYTHONINCLUDE=<PATH-TO-CONDA>/miniconda3/include/python3.8
PYTHONLIB=<PATH-TO-CONDA>/miniconda3/lib/

FUNCTIONNAME=libswap

g++ -fpic -shared -o $FUNCTIONNAME.so hello.cpp -I$PYTHONINCLUDE -I$BOOSTINCLUDE -L$PYTHONLIB -lpython3.8 -L/Users/christian.andriss/Documents/Programming/Libs/boost_1_75_0/stage/lib -lboost_python38 -lboost_numpy38

$PYTHON test.py
```

My C++ code looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/python/numpy.hpp>
#include <boost/python.hpp>

using namespace std;
namespace bp = boost::python;
namespace np = boost::python::numpy;

void swap(double *array);
void wrap_swap(np::ndarray const & array);

void swap(double *array) {
  double tmp = array[0];
  array[0] = array[1];
  array[1] = tmp;
  return;
}

void wrap_swap(np::ndarray const & array){
  //swap(reinterpret_cast<double*>(array.get_data()));
  std::cout << "Hello, Python!\n";
  return;
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(libswap)
{
  Py_Initialize();
  np::initialize();
  bp::def("swap", wrap_swap);
}
```

In order to avoid that the wrapping causes the problems, I simply print to the command line when Python calls the wrap_swap function.

My Python script looks like this:

```
import libswap
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([1.0,2.0])

libswap.swap(arr.astype(np.double))

print(arr)
```

Everything works when I omit the Py_Initialize(). However, if I include it, I get the following error:

```
Error processing line 1 of <PATH-TO-CONDA>/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib-3.3.4-py3.8-nspkg.pth:

Fatal Python error: init_import_size: Failed to import the site module
Python runtime state: initialized
...
```

Does anybody have a clue what the problem is?

Comment: It should be noted: The script works fine without Py_Initialize(). However, it is said in the Boost Python documentation that it should be called.

Comment: The error you posted looks like its searching for matplotlib and has nothing to do with your module